# Is passing interface to AsyncTask a good practice

Tags: android, interface, android-asynctask

I have an interface class

```
public interface AsyncTaskExecuteCommand {
public Object executeCommand(String jsonLocation) throws IOException,JSONException;
}
```

And I have a HashMap which store instances of this interface

```
public static HashMap<String,AsyncTaskExecuteCommand> executeCommandHashMap

executeCommandHashMap.put(COMMAND_CORE_FIELD_FETCH, new AsyncTaskExecuteCommand() {
        @Override
        public Object executeCommand(String jsonLocation) throws IOException, JSONException{
                           //return some thing
        }
    });

executeCommandHashMap.put(COMMAND_REGISTER_FIELD_FETCH, new AsyncTaskExecuteCommand() {
        @Override
        public Object executeCommand(String jsonLocation) throws IOException,
                JSONException {
                          //return some thing
        }
    });
```

And my AsyncTask named GeneralAsyncTask includes

```
doInBackground(){

 AsyncTaskExecuteCommand asyncTaskExecuteCommand = executeCommandHashMap.get(params[0]);
 return asyncTaskExecuteCommand.executeCommand(params[1]);
}
```

And this AsyncTask is called

```
new GeneralAsyncTask().execute(COMMAND_REGISTER_FIELD_FETCH,"http://something");
```

I have done this because the general structure of my AsyncTask remains the same i.e.,it does some method execution and return some value.Only method execution type and return value will be different.If I won't implement passing interface to async task,I end up creating lots of AsyncTask classes.
So,is this method a good to way to tackle my scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface makes sense if you are going to code the implementations and have them as separate classes in some package. This improves readability. If the purpose is not writing the AsynkTask each time, because it has some common parts but only the doInBackground changes, then I'd extend the AsyncTask to a concrete generic class accepting a GENERIC interface like this one:

```
    public interface MyTask<T,R> {
        R doInBackground(T... param);
    }
```

The class would be something like this (not tested):

```
    public class MyAsyncTask<T, P, R> extends AsyncTask<T, P, R> {
        private MyTask<T,R> task;

        public MyAsyncTask(MyTask<T,R> todo){
            task = todo;
        }

        protected R doInBackground(T... params) {
            if(task != null){
                return task.doInBackground(params);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        //Other AsyncTask mandatory methods implemented here. 

    }
```

Or if you are fine without generics, then do the interface and the AsyncTask subclass non generic. Either way, I'd code the task(s) class(es) and command implementations, put them on a package, make them singletons (or have public references in some main class) and get rid of the map.

Comment: **Either way, I'd code the task(s) class(es) and command implementations, put them on a package, make them singletons (or have public references in some main class) and get rid of the map.**  I have already created separate class for both AsyncTask and Interface. So instead of putting on map,are you saying that I should have a class with public static access modifiers, consisting of objects of interface like `//some class                        public static MyTask COMMAND_EXECUTE = new MyTask(){//some action}`.If possible could you give some code hint on how to implement it

Comment: I agree; if you want to pass the functions around as objects, then doing what you suggest is good.

Comment: @laaptu The way of instantiating the objects will depend on your needs. For instance, if you are going to use a given command more than once in your code, creating a new instance each time is a bit of waste. In these cases, when the classes doesn't have state but are mainly encapsulated procedures, i'd have the public references in the same place as the map was, or in each command class (singleton pattern), or better, have your own AsyncTaskExectuteCommandFactory somewhere (factory pattern).

Comment: @Mister Smith: though i haven't used factory pattern,i will surely study it and implement it and thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a lot of complexity. Is there a reason you just don't use an anonymous class:

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, Object>() {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... url) {
        //return some thing
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        // do something with result
    }
}.execute("http://something");
```

Comment: I never thought of putting an Anonymous class as stated by @Mister Smith.I would give it a try and let know ,if it works in my case

Comment: It just depends what you want to do. If you actually want a Command pattern so that you can pass the function around as objects, then doing what you and @Mister Smith suggest is good. However, if you simply want to run something in the background, the anonymous AsyncTask is better.